# Is NSFileManager.removeItemAtPath asynchronous?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfilemanager, synchronous

Nothing on that in the documentation, it seems that the method should be synchronous, it even returns a success value.
I have a UITableView with some cells, and the user can delete items associated with these cells. This calls the following code:

```
if(manager.fileExistsAtPath(vidUrl.path!))
{
    do
    {
        try manager.removeItemAtURL(vidUrl)
    }
    catch 
    {
        NSLog("failed to delete video at path \(vidUrl)")
    }
}
// reload the table data here
```

But everytime this is called the file still exists when the table data is reloaded. I don't see any way to pass a completion block to the file manager to be executed upon file deletion. The NSFileManager delegate only has "should" methods but no "did" method.

I ended up adding these very hacky lines after the catch statement which work, but surely there is a better way to handle this?

```
while(manager.fileExistsAtPath(vidUrl.path!))
{
    usleep(5000)
}
```

**EDIT**
Complete code below (this is triggered by a UIAlertAction)

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: ok, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler:{
    (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    HUD.show(HUDContentType.LabeledProgress(title: deleteString, subtitle: "Deleting..."))
    for item in self.selectedVideos
    {
        let vidUrl = (item as! VideoItem).filePath
        if(manager.fileExistsAtPath(vidUrl.path!))
        {
            do
            {
                try manager.removeItemAtURL(vidUrl)
                // If I remove this while loop then files still exist in the loadVideos below
                while(manager.fileExistsAtPath(vidUrl.path!))
                {
                    usleep(5000)
                }
            }
            catch {NSLog("failed to delete video at path \(vidUrl)")}
        }
    }
    self.loadVideos()
    HUD.hide()
})
```

and the loadVideos function

```
func loadVideos()
{
    self.videos.removeAll()
    let documentsUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
    do {
        let width = self.collectionView!.bounds.width * 0.4
        let targetSize = CGSizeMake(width,width)
        let directoryContents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL( documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
        let vidFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == VIDEO_EXTENSION }
        let validUrls = NSMutableArray()
        for vid in vidFiles
        {
            let thumbDuration = GalleryThumbLoader.getVideoThumb(vid.absoluteURL, size: targetSize)
            let video = VideoItem(filePath: vid.absoluteURL, bitmap: thumbDuration.bitmap, duration: thumbDuration.duration)
            videos.append(video)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            {
                self.collectionView!.reloadData()
            })
            validUrls.addObject(vid.absoluteURL.path!)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
        videos = [VideoItem]()
    }
    NSLog("finished loading videos")
}
```

Comment: Can u post the complete code?

Comment: `reloadData()` in a repeat loop is very expensive. Put it after the repeat loop.

Comment: ok but that has nothing to do with the problem reported. The problem is that vidFiles contains the files I have just deleted if I don't sleep for a bit

Comment: Why don't you just remove the items from `self.videos`? That's less expensive than retrieving the entire directory? And what's `validUrls` for? It's actually not used.

Comment: I suspect it is async too, my unit tests are getting messed up with the assumption that its sync. Have you found any official answer or confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

You do it on sub thread!

you will judge it before handle file.like this: 
[NSThread isMainThread];